# What does いつも mean in this context

Tags: meaning, manga

I can't figure out the meaning of いつもいつも in this dialogue.

If I understand correctly the girl is asking the other two girls to free up some space for her (to hug the girl in the middle). But I can't understand what's inside the bubble. Like "You always, always..." and the asks them to free up some space? Doesn't make much sense to me.

[image]

Comment: A verb is omitted after いつもいつも. I think the full sentence looks something like「あなたらはいつもいつもそんなことをしやがって」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said, a verb is omitted (or rather, a lot of the sentence). The full sentence is probably something like あんたらはいつもいつもそんなことをしている.

Literally, that sentence is just "you guys always always", and so in English, the part left out is "do this".